# Is there a reason why previous conversation is not shown in empathy?

Tags: empathy, google-talk

I use Google Talk (chat) in Gmail, Google Plus, Empathy, and on my Android Phone. All but empathy show the messages made in any of the others making it easy to move between my phone and gmail without having to check what it was I was talking about.

Is there a reason Empathy can not or does not do this?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question a bit? You mean to say that when you shift from chat in gmail to Android phone, it shows you the last conversation you were having on gmail on your desktop/laptop? Strangely, I can't do that

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying, my Android phone always shows all the messages I have sent regardless of what client I have sent them, same with Google Talk on the web but not in Empathy.

Comment: I don't think that feature is available in Empathy

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)